# Separate several strings with the same identifier

Tags: c#, regex

How to separate several  strings  with the same identifier ( which follow one another sequentially in original text).

for example, I have large text and needed to match groups of strings with identifier **"rtsp-video"** .

```
set service "rtsp-video" protocol tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 80-80 
set service "rtsp-video" + udp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554 
set service "rtsp-video" + tcp src-port 0-65535 dst-port 554-554
```

How to make REGEXP pattern correctly?

```
         ................................... 
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
 string patternService = @"(set service "".+""){1,}.*";
 var matchesService = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), patternService);

          foreach (Match match in matchesService)
               {

                    lst_app.Add(match.ToString());

               }
            }


            return lst_app;
```

Comment: You said you need to match `rtsp-video`, but your Regex certainly isn't matching *on that.* What is it you want?

Comment: The problem with your `.+` pattern is that once it reaches the double quote `"`, it continues right through it. You should use `[^""]+` instead. This would also avoid backtracking.

Comment: Match strings that contains "rtsp-video". That's right

Comment: @user3214034: so that comment didn't add anything to the question. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
^.*?\"rtsp-video\".*?$
```

Would that work? You might have to change some settings for it to process line ending correctly. C# is weird that way.

Just a though ... why not use:

```
lst_app = File.ReadAllLines(opendialog.FileName).Where(w=>w.Contains("\"rtsp-video\"")).ToList();
```

Cheers.